# WordPress Media Library: Custom tab content displayed in "Media Library" tab

Tags: javascript, media-library

I write a WordPress plugin that is adding a custom tab in the Media Library.

Problem is that sometimes when I open `wp.media.frame` content from custom tab is displayed inside of Media Library tab.

Like this:

[image]

**My Code**

```
var frame = wp.media.view.MediaFrame.Post;
wp.media.view.MediaFrame.Post = frame.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        frame.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);

        var State = wp.media.controller.State.extend({
            insert: function() {
                console.log("Bla");
                this.frame.close();
            }
        })

        this.states.add([
            new State({
                id: 'custom',
                search: false,
                title: 'Custom'
            })
        ]);

        this.on('content:render:custom', this.renderUnsplashTabContent, this);
    },

    browseRouter: function(routerView) {
        routerView.set({
            upload: {
                text:     wp.media.view.l10n.uploadFilesTitle,
                priority: 20
            },
            custom: {
                text: wp.media.view.l10n.customTitle,
                priority: 30
            },
            browse: {
                text:     wp.media.view.l10n.mediaLibraryTitle,
                priority: 40
            },
        });
    },

    renderCustomTabContent: function() {
        var CustomView = wp.Backbone.View.extend({
            tagName: 'div',
            className: 'custom',
            template: wp.template('custom')
        })

        var view = new CustomView({
            data: data.frogs,
        });

        this.content.set(view);
    },
});
```

Did anyone got this problem?